# updating image uploaded file

Tags: php, html, mysql

Can you help me to update the images from my sample project?

Here's my code:

```
$dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/test/individualpictures/";
            $names = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"];
            $temp = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"];
            $uploadfile = $dir . basename($names);

<input type="file" name='uploadedfile'></input>
<input type="submit name="update"></input>

if(isset($update)){ 
   mysql_query("UPDATE contact_individual SET attachment='$uploadedfile'
   WHERE contactID_individual='$text'");
}
```

Take note that I have already the url of the image saved in my database, and all I wanted is that when the user did not make any actions, the url that was saved to my database will not be replaced with a blank url. thanks!

Comment: you have used $uploadfile to save path in db so just use $dir = $dir.basename($names) that will work too...it will show error if no file is selected so u can also check for file is uploaded or not then add it to db.

Comment: but what i wanted to happen is that, when i am updating the profile for instance the image/uploaded file will not replace the saved path in the database

Comment: how to add a default value for this type of form?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as following way.

Sample Code.

```
<?php
    $dir   = "C:/xampp/htdocs/test/individualpictures/";
    $names = isset($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]) ? $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"] : '';
    $temp  = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"];
    $dir   = $dir . basename($names);

    echo '<input type="file" name="uploadedfile" />';
    echo '<input type="submit name="update" />';

    if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
        mysql_query("UPDATE contact_individual SET attachment='$dir' WHERE contactID_individual='$text'");
    }
?>
```

Comment: i think my only problem is how to put a default value on this type of form.

Comment: whola you are absolutely right if u see $names i changed your code and added turnery if condition.

Comment: <input type='file' name='uploadedfile' value="<?echo $dataattachment;?>"></input>

Comment: but when i clicked the update button, the path has been replaced with a blank path.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple check whether there is any update being made. I mean you can check whether the file name is blank or not. Based on that you can update the table or dont update.